# In R, extract files from a 7z files (ftp) and save

Tags: r

I have a 7.z file via some ftp site:
ftp://.../2009/file.7z
I would like to extract(or unzip) the files inside and save its in a directory "C:/myfiles"

I can't do this!
Some help?

## Edited

I do this, but it does not work.

```
zipF <- ftp://.../2009/file.7z
outDir<-getwd() # Define the folder where the zip file should be unzipped to 
unzip(zipF,exdir=outDir)  # unzip your file 
Warning message:
In unzip(zipF, exdir = outDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

After this, my directory is empty.

Comment: Check here:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/unzip.html   You can unzip using `unzip` and save anwhere you like by `setwd("your path")` and saving the files. It is pretty simple.

Comment: It does not work. I edited my question.